# One entity, several models in different bounded contexts with different databases

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Let's say we have an `Order` entity that will be modeled in 2 diff. BCs in a e-commerce application.

The first BC is `Order Placement`. This BC takes care of collecting all orders placed by our customers from our different websites, validates them and populates its corresponding database by Orders with state either `Placed` or `Rejected`.

The 2nd BC is `Shipment`. This allows the employees in the warehouses to mark an Order as `Shipped` in its database once it leaves the warehouse.

Now since both BCs use different databases which are empty at first, there will be a need to inform the `Shipment` BC of the orders that were `Placed`, so that when a scanner wants to `Ship` an `Order` it will be there in the `Shipment` BC.

My initial approach was to create a domain event once an `Order` is placed in the `Order placement` BC and have the `Shipment` BC subscribe to that event and create a corresponding `Order` entity in its database for every order placed.

However, I can't stop that feeling that I'm duplicating data across different databases.

My second approach is to ask the `Order Placement` each time an order is being `Shipped` for an `Order` entity, but I still need to maintain the state of the Order in case a failure of a failure in the shipment.

Is there a better approach to all this from a DDD POV?

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach is perfectly fine in my opinion. You are not duplicating data, because as you already noticed, that data is from another context. Same data in different contexts means different things.

Comment: +1 I couldn't have said it better. Also: Data duplication is not a bad thing. As long as there is one context that owns a piece of information and other contexts just replicate it.

Answer (score 2):

As Vernon Vaughn pointed out in his book «Implementing Domain Driven Design»: "A greater degree of autonomy can be achieved when dependent state is already in place in our local system. Some may think of this as a cache of whole dependent objects, but that’s not usually the case when using DDD. Instead we create local domain objects translated from the foreign model, maintaining only the minimal amount of state needed by the local model.”
So copying data is okay as long as it is the only data other BCs need.
But he also mentions that if you use exact copies, it might be a sign of a modeling problem.